# CVS download on windows 10 laptop

Tags: cvs

I am very new to CVS concurrent versioning system. I want to install the server as well as a client to access the same on my windows 10 laptop.

Can you please let me know if CVS supports on windows.

and need the link to the downloadable softwares

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CVS is available for windows.

e.g. **SmartCVS**

http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/

But I would highly recomment **Git** instead of CVS.

https://git-scm.com/

Comment: I would highly recommend *Git* too. Not only because CVS isn´t actively developed anymore, but because Git has many advantages too..

Comment: I would concur. CVS requires setting up a heavyweight server. With git, there is no heavyweight server.